# How can i make my own App Store for iOS apps

Tags: ios, app-store

I have been searching for how to make my own App Store so that the user can download apps made by me through my own App Store.
I heard about Volume Purchase Program but that is not available in INDIA.I want to distribute my own business apps to my clients through my own App Store.

Comment: iOS is not like Android. So, there is no way to do that. You probably will be sued if you want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

An enterprise distribution certificate can be used to sign apps that are distributed outside of the App Store. There are terms and conditions on its use, however, which may not match your intended use (for example, it's only intended for distribution within a business, and you're not supposed to charge users to install).

For an actual App Store storefront, you can look at a third party like Apperian, or try and roll your own - creating working download links that install apps from a server isn't very hard and there are instructions [provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/gettingstarted/).

Comment: @jrturton thanks for the answer,i want my clients to install apps through a app of mine, i am able to make them downloaded from that app but when the users installed the app,i want the App Store app of mine should know whether the app is installed or not.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean - it's quite hard for one app to know if others are installed. It's probably worth asking a separate question just for that.